# Comparar valores de campos de duas tabelas excel em ficheiros diferentes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho duas tabelas em 2 ficheiros excel, e quero comparar cada valor da coluna A do ficheiro_1 com cada valor da coluna A do ficheiro_2 e ainda cada valor da coluna F do ficheiro_1 com cada valor da coluna H do ficheiro_2. Se se verificar igualdade em ambos os casos, então o campo da coluna F do ficheiro_1 deve mudar de cor.

Cada valor de cada coluna vai comparar com todos os valores da respetiva coluna no outro ficheiro.

Em pseudocódigo ficaria assim:

```
if(A1_file1 == A1_file2 && F1_file1 == H1_file2){
      F1 muda de cor.
}
```

Comment: Se postar um exemplo, com imagens ou algum dado pode ajudar bastante. Creio que poderia tentar usar **PROCV** para isso...

Comment: O **PROCV** deverá estar na formatação condicional para isso... dê uma olhada em um modelo aqui: https://github.com/excelguru/controle-obrigacao/raw/master/Controle%20de%20Obrigacoes.xlsx